# SQL - Selecting the rows with max timestamp by group

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, top-n

I have this table

```
SITE   S_ID   BAN   COUNT   P       V   TIMESTAMP
23     1       4    1500    0,05    50  10/05/17 09:58:22,609000000
23     3       3    800     0,05    50  10/05/17 09:58:22,736000000
23     2       3    3000    0,05    50  10/05/17 09:58:22,674000000
23     1       4    1500    0,05    50  10/05/17 15:57:04,079000000
23     1       4    1499    0,05    50  10/05/17 15:53:38,851000000
20     1       3    2000    0,1     50  10/05/17 10:57:07,172000000
20     2       3    2000    0,1     50  10/05/17 10:59:50,127000000
20     3       2    3000    0,1     50  10/05/17 11:00:39,051000000
20     4       2    3000    0,1     50  10/05/17 11:01:15,533000000
```

and I'm trying to obtain something like this:

```
SITE   S_ID   BAN   COUNT   P       V   TIMESTAMP
23     3       3    800     0,05    50  10/05/17 09:58:22,736000000
23     2       3    3000    0,05    50  10/05/17 09:58:22,674000000
23     1       4    1500    0,05    50  10/05/17 15:57:04,079000000
20     1       3    2000    0,1     50  10/05/17 10:57:07,172000000
20     2       3    2000    0,1     50  10/05/17 10:59:50,127000000
20     3       2    3000    0,1     50  10/05/17 11:00:39,051000000
20     4       2    3000    0,1     50  10/05/17 11:01:15,533000000
```

i.e. for every SITE the S_ID, BAN, COUNT, P, V and TIMESTAMP with the MAX(TIMESTAMP)

Comment: this is a simple `group by`. have you tried doing that?

Comment: Yes I did. The problem is that the query returns two S_ID =1 to the SITE number 23. And I oinly need the one with the max timestamp

Comment: add a where-clause then? `WHERE TIMESTAMP = MAX(TIMESTAMP)`

Comment: This didn't work

Comment: What S_ID do you want if there are 2 for the same site?

Comment: I want all of them, but the ones with max timestamp. For example, for site 23, I want S_ID 1,2 and 3, but the last ones.

Comment: Is my answer what your looking for?

Comment: Yeah!, Thanks JBdev!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
SELECT 
    SITE
    , S_ID
    ,BAN
    ,COUNT
    ,P
    ,V
    ,TimeStamp
FROM [Your Table Name]
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        SITE
        , S_ID
        , MAX(TIMESTAMP) as MaxTimeStamp 
    FROM [Your Table Name] 
    GROUP BY 
        SITE 
        , S_ID
    ) AS MaxDAata ON
        MaxData.SITE = [Your Table Name].SITE 
        AND MaxData.S_ID = [Your Table Name].S_ID
       AND MaxData.TimeStamp = [Your Table Name].MaxTimeStamp
```

Comment: It sounds like I need to update this to group by S_ID too

Comment: Updated it to return all uniq site, s_id combinations, but only return the max row for each uniq pair.

Answer (score 0):

I would make use of an analytic function to rank the dates within a group (partition) then only return the top ranked items.  I'm not sure your partition so I used the fields `site, s_id, ban`

```
select * from 
    (with test_data (SITE,   S_ID,   BAN,   s_COUNT,   P,       V,   s_TIMESTAMP) as (
    select 23,     1,       4,    1500,    0.05,    50,  to_timestamp('10/05/17 09:58:22,609','MM/DD/YY HH24:MI:SS,FF') from dual union all
    select 23,     3,       3,    800 ,    0.05,    50,  to_timestamp('10/05/17 09:58:22,736','MM/DD/YY HH24:MI:SS,FF') from dual union all
    select 23,     2,       3,    3000,    0.05,    50,  to_timestamp('10/05/17 09:58:22,674','MM/DD/YY HH24:MI:SS,FF') from dual union all
    select 23,     1,       4,    1500,    0.05,    50,  to_timestamp('10/05/17 15:57:04,079','MM/DD/YY HH24:MI:SS,FF') from dual union all
    select 23,     1,       4,    1499,    0.05,    50,  to_timestamp('10/05/17 15:53:38,851','MM/DD/YY HH24:MI:SS,FF') from dual union all
    select 20,     1,       3,    2000,    0.1 ,    50,  to_timestamp('10/05/17 10:57:07,172','MM/DD/YY HH24:MI:SS,FF') from dual union all
    select 20,     2,       3,    2000,    0.1 ,    50,  to_timestamp('10/05/17 10:59:50,127','MM/DD/YY HH24:MI:SS,FF') from dual union all
    select 20,     3,       2,    3000,    0.1 ,    50,  to_timestamp('10/05/17 11:00:39,051','MM/DD/YY HH24:MI:SS,FF') from dual union all
    select 20,     4,       2,    3000,    0.1 ,    50,  to_timestamp('10/05/17 11:01:15,533','MM/DD/YY HH24:MI:SS,FF') from dual
    )
    SELECT site, s_id, ban, s_count, p, v, s_timestamp, 
           rank() over (partition by site, s_id, ban order by s_timestamp desc) as r
    FROM test_data
    )
where r = 1
order by site, s_id


SITE|S_ID|BAN|S_COUNT|P|V|S_TIMESTAMP|R
20|1|3|2000|0.1|50|05-OCT-17 10.57.07.172000000 AM|1
20|2|3|2000|0.1|50|05-OCT-17 10.59.50.127000000 AM|1
20|3|2|3000|0.1|50|05-OCT-17 11.00.39.051000000 AM|1
20|4|2|3000|0.1|50|05-OCT-17 11.01.15.533000000 AM|1
23|1|4|1500|0.05|50|05-OCT-17 03.57.04.079000000 PM|1
23|2|3|3000|0.05|50|05-OCT-17 09.58.22.674000000 AM|1
23|3|3|800|0.05|50|05-OCT-17 09.58.22.736000000 AM|1
```